# Subsonic 3.0 General Questions

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

Ok,

I was eagerly awaiting the release of subsonic 3.0 to use as my low-level data layer, and now its out.  I'm currently using the ActiveRecord templates (having tried both the repository and advanced templates) and I have one HUGE request and a few questions:

Request:  Other than bug fixes, Rob please spend the time to provide documentation.  I don't mean 5 examples, I mean API complete documentation.  Here's why:

I'm testing subsonic by writing ASP.NET MembershipProvider and RoleProvider classes and simple questions continually slow me up using subsonic:

Q.  Assuming I have a class 'User' and I update/save/delete a record using

```
user.Save();
```

I need information on how to get success/failure?  Do I look for an exception on failure or can I get a count of 'affected' records (old school?)

Q.  If I get an exception, which exception(s) can I expect?

I'll have more issues, but I really believe a good functional API documentation would solve the problem.

If the answer is 'read the source code', then I'm sure you're going to chase quite a few developers away from subsonic.  I really want to use the library, but the point is "use" the library, not reverse engineer it.

-Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q. I need information on how to get success/failure? Do I look for an exception on failure or can I get a count of 'affected' records (old school?)

If it doesn't throw an exception then it's worked

Q. If I get an exception, which exception(s) can I expect?

You can expect a [DbException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbexception.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it seems obvious but I was unsure if Rob was using custom exception classes for Subsonic.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use custom exceptions. I spent 5 weeks writing docs - so yah I did spend some time on this. You could also find your answer there as well: http://subsonicproject.com/docs

Comment: I've seen your doc pages Rob and there's nothing wrong with them, but not enough and its certainly not organized enough.  I understand limited resources and the complexity of documentation, I've done it myself.  Tutorials and examples are great to get going, but nit-picky api reference is what would be amazing.  I'd even accept good comments that generate auto-doc type information.  Simply and easy place to lookup function calls, parameters and what does it do.

Still, thanks for a great product, the more I use it, the more I enjoy it. -Jeff

Comment: Open Source isn't supposed to be one person trying to make something "acceptable" to others. I'm not picking on you - I'm not trying to be a jerk either. I need help and I find that people have (for the most part) preferred to complain rather than dig in and help out. It's the landscape.

Answer (score 0):

3.0 is a little too buggy for me so far. I think I am going back to 2.x for now, thanks for all the hard work though.